# Minor syntax highlighting error in stack-snippet

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

> [image: A minor bug fix in stack-snippet]

I have a screen shot of a coding in stack-snippet from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189736/functionjs-only-works-for-the-highest-div-quote), the snippet has no problem when executed but the syntax highlighting is a bit buggy, in the screenshot, there is a variable `quote` and another variable `quotewords`, but when highlighting `quotewords` it makes a minor mistake in that case ( see the image )

Comment: Is this on one of the apps? I can neither reproduce this on mobile nor on desktop.

Comment: I took the screen shot from desktop

Comment: Possibly it's gone now , even I can't find it again , maybe the bug has been fixed

Comment: Then, it may have been testing of correctly handling the syntax highlighting of JS template literals.

Comment: Umm , I don't get it ?

Comment: Support for template literals in syntax highlighting has been [requested recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367096/4642212), though it’s actually unlikely that this has something to do with your bug.