# Syntax highlighting for JavaScript does not support template literals on Stack Overflow, but does on Meta

Tags: bug, meta, syntax-highlighting

I just realized that syntax highlighting for [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) is different on Meta Stack Overflow compared to Stack Overflow.

Meta:

[image]

Stack Overflow:

[image]

Ignoring the different colors, you can see that the template literals are being highlighted in the Meta example, but on the Stack Overflow example, they are being treated as normal code.

Why is this? Is there any reason as to why the syntax highlighting is different on one site than another?

Inspired by this question - [Add support for template literals to the JavaScript syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367096/add-support-for-template-literals-to-the-javascript-syntax-highlighter)

Comment: *[JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)* it is (not *Javascript*).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Changed the title

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow are currently running different syntax highlighters:

- MSO (and MSE) are running highlight.js as of 10th September
- SO (and the rest of the network) are running prettify

The plan is to roll out highlight.js to the rest of the network 24th September.

This is all described in the [MSE highlight.js announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983).